# Why did the system identify this question as spam?

Tags: support, review-queue, spam

I was visiting the review queue when this question [How does one operate in an "Dark Scrum" environment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158557/how-does-one-operate-in-an-dark-scrum-environment) came up with the note

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully.

I don't understand why that would be the case, since it seems like a valid question with an extensive answer. Is there an explanation that I don't see?

Edit: [This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/99951) is what I found in the review history, though the notice is gone. So I don't know if this is the right link.

Comment: Could you link to the actual review event please? It should be visible in your review history.

Comment: @tripleee I tried and edited the question, not sure if I did it right though.

Comment: Maybe the word "dark" is bad?

Answer (score 7):

It might have been posted from an IP address which has been used to post spam in the past, or to suggest edits which contain spam. Such IP addresses are hobbled or even blocked from posting, by a system nicknamed [SpamRam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=spamram) (not sure if there's a canonical post about it); the user posting that question *could* have noticed that because they had to complete a Captcha.

There is [some additional information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216399/295232) (thanks @Lilienthal) about this message on Meta Stack Exchange. That this is a [false positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) (i.e. not spam) isn't uncommon; I do quite a lot of reviews across the network and I'd say that about 50% of the times I see that message it's really spam, and 50% just an innocent user like here.

Thanks for reviewing it carefully, as indicated by the message.

Comment: Authorative answer is on main meta: [The review system suggested something was probably spam, what should I do when I see this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216399)